# Does template constructor with universal reference hide move construtor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does this template ctor hide move ctor?

```
class A {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        A(T &&t);

        // move would be as this:
        /*
            A(A &&a);
        */
};
```

And how in this situation should I implement move ctor then? Should it be with default syntax `A (A &&)` or a template specialization?

Comment: It appears that in gcc at least, the templated ctor is not considered when moving: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c995d34b40fb4bc if that's the case according to standard, then you can implement move ctor in the usual way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard (draft)

[class.copy]

> 3 A **non-template** constructor for class X is a move constructor if its first parameter is of type X&&, const X&&, volatile X&&, or const volatile X&&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6). [ Example: Y::Y(Y&&) is a move constructor.

Only non-template constructors can be move constructors. Same applies to copy constructors<sup>†</sup>. Therefore the implicit move constructor is generated.

You implement the move constructor in the usual way. Specialization won't work because the implicit non-template move constructor is preferred by the overload resolution.

<sup>†</sup> If the argument type does not match exactly to `const T&`, however, the templated reference wins the overload resolution. This can easily happen as can be seen in Praveen's example.

Comment: **Same applies to copy constructors**. `A a2{a1};` calls `template` instead of the `copy constructor`. why?  http://ideone.com/JAfjLy

Comment: @Praveen because `a1` isn't `const`. Forwarding references are really greedy.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is incorrect. While it is true that: `template <typename T> A(T &&t) { }` is not a move constructor, you already knew that. The compiler will implicitly declare a move constructor in this case and normal overload resolution will work as expected:

```
A a{2}; // calls template
A b = std::move(a); // calls move
A c{a}; // calls template
```

There is nothing precluding `a` from being moved into `c`, even though the template constructor isn't a "move" constructor.

Comment: How do you know the asker knows that the template doesn't count as a move constructor? Where does it say in the accepted answer that no move constructor is implicitly declared? (or what does _"the accepted answer is incorrect"_ refer to?)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the accepted answer, if you don't have a user-defined copy constructor, it may cause a problem when you do

```
A a(/*args*/);
// 'a' is a lvalue here. So even though the compiler will implicitly
// generate a copy constructor (i.e. A(const A&) ), it will not 
// be used here because the template better matches the input type.
A a1(a);
```

To avoid this, you should use the SFINAE to suppress matching the template as a copy constructor in case you don't intend to have a user-defined constructor, so that the implicit copy constructor will be chosen. Or just define a A(A&) constructor.